# deepCopy for all fields and arrays contained in an object AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to copy some fields in another fields for the same object like in this demo :

```
var customers = {
    apple: {
        papa: {
            en: "cool" 
        }
    },
    oranges: {
        papa: {
            en: "cool" 
        }
    } 
};

function deepCopyEn(src) {


    if (src.hasOwnProperty("en")) {
      src.fr = src.en;
      src.es = src.en;
    }
    else {
        if (src.constructor === Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
                deepCopyEn(src[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var prop in src) {
                if(src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    deepCopyEn(src[prop]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

deepCopyEn(customers);

console.log(customers);
```

but when I tried with a class with an array and another filed the function don't work, this is an example http://pastebin.com/K7EjAnu1 it gives this error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Any help to update my function??

Comment: Any chance of using Jquery?

Comment: No, I'm already working with angularJs for the rest of my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for scalar types ...

```
function deepCopyEn(src) {


    if((/string|number|boolean/).test(typeof src)) {
        return;
    }

    if (src.hasOwnProperty("en")) {
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need